# How do I include a mPDF file?

Tags: php

I have no problem creating PDF with mPDF as bellow:

```
$html = '
// Here's the HTML table code
';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
```

But how can I include files here?

```
$html = '
include(files.php)
';
OR
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file.php,2);
```

where file.php file has HTML and php codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use following to retrieve the html from the target php file and write it to PDF:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "files.php";
$html = ob_get_clean();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
```